# How to change option name in Drupal 8 form element?

Tags: forms, drupal-8

I have sort link 'Best' in exposed form. I want after user click this link, link title changes to 'New'

I'm try this, but it don't work:

```
function helper_form_views_exposed_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form['#id']== 'views-exposed-form-pozdravleniya-taxonomy-term-page-1') {
      $form['sort_by']['#title'] = '';
      $form['sort_by']['#options']['created'] = '';
      if ($form['sort_by']['#value'] == 'count') {
        $form['sort_by']['#options']['count'] = 'New';
      }
    }
}
```

Also I'm try this, it don't work too:

```
function helper_form_views_exposed_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form['#id']== 'views-exposed-form-pozdravleniya-taxonomy-term-page-1') {
      $form['sort_by']['#title'] = '';
      $form['sort_by']['#options']['created'] = '';
      if ($form_state->getValue('sort_by') == 'count') {
        $form['sort_by']['#options']['count'] = 'New';
      }
    }
}
```

[Screenshot form dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kqdy8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
$form_state->getUserInput()['sort_by']
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!
`function helper_form_views_exposed_form_alter(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form['#id']== 'views-exposed-form-pozdravleniya-taxonomy-term-page-1') {
      $form['sort_by']['#title'] = '';
      $form['sort_by']['#options']['created'] = '';
      if ($form_state->getUserInput()['sort_by'] == 'count') {
        $form['sort_by']['#options']['count'] = 'New';
      }
    }
}`